# SVG SMIL animateTransform easing

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I am trying to add a timing function to a simple SVG SMIL animation. Apparently timing/easing can be set with the `keySplines` attribute, however in my example it does not work:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="214" height="214" viewBox="0 0 24 24">

    <rect style="fill:#000;" width="4" height="4" x="3" y="11">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
        begin="0s" dur="2s" type="translate" from="0 0" to="40 0" repeatCount="4" fill="freeze"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1"/>
    </rect>

    <rect style="fill:#ff0000;" width="4" height="4" x="3" y="16">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
        begin="0s" dur="2s" type="translate" from="0 0" to="40 0" repeatCount="4" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>

</svg>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q4e4049s/ , the black one should have easing

Comment: Seems OK to me on Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, looks right in Firefox but fails in Chrome. Bug? Different syntax?

Comment: Bug in Chrome. You should report it.

Comment: Works if you add `keyTimes="0;1"`, essentially you're depending on an implicit `keyTimes` if you don't add that, which seems fine to me. The SVG spec is IMHO not 100% clear that an implicit `keyTimes` should be used in this case.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Indeed that did the trick in Chrome. Thank you

Comment: This has been reported before, http://crbug.com/101374.

Comment: I've also filed a bug report, guess that I should close that one

Answer (score 9):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 14">
    <rect fill="black" width="6" height="6" x="3" y="0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
                          begin="0s"
                          dur="2s"
                          type="translate"
                          from="0 0"
                          to="40 0"
                          repeatCount="4"
                          fill="freeze"
                          calcMode="spline"
                          keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1; 0.4 0 0.2 1"
                          values="0;30;0"/>
    </rect>
    <rect fill="red" width="6" height="6" x="3" y="7">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          begin="0s"
                          dur="2s"
                          type="translate"
                          from="0 0"
                          to="40 0"
                          repeatCount="4"
                          fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: what are `values="0;30;0"`

Comment: @Necktwi "values" is like "from" and "to", Except it is more flexible because you can have more than 2 key frames. Here for example you go from "0" to "30", then back to "0". Which is not possible with just "from/to".

Comment: can you explain this please?

Comment: the `from` and `to` are ignored when you add the `value` attribute, they actually don't even need to be in there.  Plus if you want to add the vertical animation to it also, you can add a "Y" value to each value `values="0 0;30 30;0 0"`

Comment: Each control point description is a set of four values: x1 y1 x2 y2, describing the Bézier control points for one time segment. The keyTimes values that define the associated segment are the Bézier "anchor points", and the keySplines values are the control points. Thus, there must be one fewer sets of control points than there are keyTimes.

The values of x1 y1 x2 y2 must all be in the range 0 to 1.  If the duration of the animation is indefinite, any keyTimes specification will be ignored.  [keySplines description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keySplines)