# How to apply CSS animation to a SVG mask in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, svg, css-transforms

I'm trying to apply a css animation to a svg mask. While it works fine on Chrome (v. 73), I'm unable to make it work on Firefox (v. 66).

I can't figure out why my current example (see below) is not working on Firefox

Note : according to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), Firefox 66 does not require any prefix for `transform` to work. I'm planning to add them for older versions support but it wouldn't solve my current issue.

Here's a small example of my issue : (HTML ids have been added for naming the objects in my explanations)

```css
.canvas {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  background: lightblue;
}

.animated {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: myAnimation 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div>
      <svg class="canvas" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="150px" height="150px">

          <defs>
            <mask id="gmask" fill="white">
              <!-- Mask is defined here as a black circle in a white background -->
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" />
              <circle id="maskCircle" class="animated" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="black" />
            </mask>
          </defs>

          <!-- Pink circle is animated in both browsers -->
          <circle id="testCircle" class="animated" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="pink" />

          <circle id="outerCircle" class="outer" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" mask="url(#gmask)" />
        </svg>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to `transform: scale` the circle `maskCircle` of size 25 from `0` to `0.8` so it creates a donut shape when applied as a mask to the `outerCircle` (of size 25 as well).

On Chrome, I can get the expected output [view in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B7cH.png) ; while in Firefox the animation is not applied, so the mask circle remain it's full size (25) and totally hide `outerCircle` [view in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7yz.png).

(Well, *almost totally* hide it, as I can see a slight line where the circle should be, but it shows even without animation, so I believe this is the mask/circle not being rendered at the exact same size and not relevant to my issue).

As a test I've applied the same animation to a simple svg object (`testCircle`, the pink circle) and it works fine. which make me think the issue is related to masks.

I suppose animating a mask is pretty common and should be possible, so my guess is that i'm doing something wrong chrome is fine with but not Firefox.

Any idea how I can make it work for both?

Comment: CSS animation is not supported on masks in Firefox as you've discovered. SMIL is supported though so if you use that instead it will work in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert said it’s better to use SVG masks that work in all modern browsers.

Instead of the scale () animation, I used the animation of the radii of the circle. This is easier because you do not have to worry about positioning the circles after the zoom.

You have a complex form of animation, so at the first stage before the black ring I applied a mask animation combination.

```
<mask id="gmask" fill="white">
 <circle id="maskCircle" class="animated" cx="50" cy="50" r="0" fill="black" >
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="r"  dur="0.8s" values="0;20" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>
</mask>
```

and outside of the ring animation of the radius of the circle

```
<circle id="testCircle"  cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="pink"  >
      <animate attributeName="r" begin="an1.end" dur="0.2s" from="25" to="40" 
         fill="freeze"/>
</circle>
```

Below is the finished code.

```css
.canvas {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  background: lightblue;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div>
      <svg class="canvas" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="150px" height="150px">

          <defs>
            <mask id="gmask" fill="white">
              <!-- Mask is defined here as a black circle in a white background -->
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" /> 
              <circle id="maskCircle" class="animated" cx="50" cy="50" r="0" fill="black" >
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="r"  dur="0.8s" values="0;20" fill="freeze" />
     </circle> 
            </mask>
          </defs>

          <!-- Pink circle is animated in both browsers --> 
    <circle id="testCircle"  cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="pink"  >
            <animate attributeName="r" begin="an1.end" dur="0.2s" from="25" to="40" fill="freeze"/>
   </circle>    
    <circle id="outerCircle" class="outer" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"  mask="url(#gmask)"/>
          

          
        </svg>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done using SMIL:

```css
.center{margin:0 auto;width:150px;}

.canvas {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div>
      <svg class="canvas" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="150px" height="150px">

          <defs>
            <mask id="gmask" fill="white">
              <!-- Mask is defined here as a black circle in a white background -->
              <rect x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" fill="white" />
              <circle id="maskCircle" class="animated"  r="25" fill="black" >
                <animateTransform 
                  attributeType="XML" 
                   attributeName="transform" 
                   type="scale"
                   values="0;.8"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1"
                   dur="1s" 
                   fill="freeze"
                    /> 
              </circle>
            </mask>
          </defs>

          <!-- Pink circle is animated in both browsers -->
        <circle id="testCircle" class="animated"  r="50" fill="pink">
          <animateTransform 
                  attributeType="XML" 
                   attributeName="transform" 
                   type="scale"
                   values="0;.8"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1"
                   dur="1s" 
                   fill="freeze"
                    /> 
        </circle>

          <circle id="outerCircle" class="outer"  r="25" mask="url(#gmask)" />
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using `calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1"` instead of easing.

See this: [SVG SMIL animateTransform easing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926999/svg-smil-animatetransform-easing)

I'm using `fill="freeze"` instead of the CSS `forwards`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Almost simultaneously :)